# How to make sass file global in create react app without ejecting?

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I am using Create React App with Foundation and I am trying to share the Sass code without having to import into every component so it's global. I read another answer and they suggested using sass-resource-loader but it seems like you have to run 'eject' to get this working, are there any alternatives?

///Foundation.scss////

```
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/vendor/normalize.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/helpers/missing-dependencies';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/helpers/true';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/contain';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/purge';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/remove';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/replace';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/to-list';

@import 'settings.scss';

@charset "UTF-8";

// Utilities
@import 'util/util.scss';

// Global styles
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/global.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/typography/typography.scss';

// Grids
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/grid/grid';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/xy-grid/xy-grid';

@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/accordion';

// Helpers
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/float';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/flex';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/visibility';
@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/prototype/prototype';

@mixin foundation-everything(
    $flex: true,
    $prototype: false
) {
    @if $flex {
        $global-flexbox: true !global;
    }

    // Global styles
    @include foundation-global-styles;
    // @include foundation-forms;
    @include foundation-typography;

    // Grids
    @if not $flex {
        @include foundation-grid;
    }
    @else {
        @if $xy-grid {
        @include foundation-xy-grid-classes;
        }
        @else {
        @include foundation-flex-grid;
        }
    }

    // Containers
    @include foundation-accordion;

    // Helpers
    @include foundation-float-classes;
    @if $flex { @include foundation-flex-classes; }
    @include foundation-visibility-classes;
    @if $prototype { @include foundation-prototype-classes; }
}

@import '../global';
```

And I am importing into my components like this, but this is too repetitive.

///Home.scss///

```
@import '../assets/foundation/Foundation.scss';
@include foundation-everything;
```

Comment: You can import in `index.js` file, so the styles will be available to every component.

Comment: @ravibagul91
I tried importing (import './assets/foundation/Foundation.scss') into index.js but then in my component scss file i get an Undefined variable error

Comment: If you are importing in `index.js` file then no need to import in component.

Comment: @ravibagul91
I moved the import to index.js and removed it from component.scss but as i am using variables from Foundation.scss i get the error